# Prononcer ce nombre

Tags: prononciation, nombres

« La racine carrée de 546 est 23,36664289109 » est une réplique extraite d'un dessin animé  que je regarde maintenant à la télévision.

Comment puis-je prononcer le nombre « 23,36664289109 » ?

Je voudrais l'écrire en toutes lettres. Jusqu'ici, je ne sais que « 23, » qui se lit « vingt-trois virgule ... ».

Comment: @M42 Merci pour votre modification de ma question. Je n'ai jamais entendu le mot « puis » ; mon professeur ne me l'a déjà pas enseigné. « Puis-je » est quelle forme du verbe pouvoir ?

Comment: @M42 *Pouvons-nous, pourriez-vous, puissent-ils* n'existent pas ?

Comment: @cl-r: Bien sûr que ces formes existent, je ne comprends pas le sens de la question.

Comment: @M42 Votre commentaire semble indiquer que seul l'indicatif présent peut prendre la forme interrogative, d'où ma question concernant les autres temps

Comment: @cl-r Je voulais dire que seule la forme « puis-je » est autorisée par rapport à « peux-je » qui, elle, ne l'est pas. Je m'aperçois que j'ai fait une horrible faute d'orthographe : « et » et lieu et place de « est ». Je recopie mon commentaire sans faute, il est trop tard pour modifier l'original.

Comment: « Je puis » est une autre forme de l'indicatif présent et la seule autorisée à la forme interrogative, voir : toutelaconjugaison.com/conjugaison-verbe-pouvoir.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L'usage est de regrouper les décimales par deux ou trois en évitant d'isoler un chiffre final. Les zéros placés en préfixe sont prononcés:

`23,36664289109` -> **vingt-trois virgule trente-six, soixante-six, quarante-deux, quatre-vingt-neuf, cent neuf** ou **vingt-trois virgule trois-cent-soixante-six [millièmes] six-cent-quarante-deux [millionnièmes] huit-cent-quatre-vingt-onze [milliardièmes] zéro neuf**.

`89,123` -> **quatre-vingt-neuf [virgule] cent-vingt-trois**

`19,0123` -> **dix-neuf [virgule] zéro un vingt-trois** ou **dix-neuf [virgule] zéro cent-vingt-trois**

`19,0012` -> **dix-neuf [virgule] zéro zéro douze**

Notes:

- le mot « virgule » est souvent omis à l'oral.
- une pause est marquée entre deux groupes présentant une ambiguïté comme `98` et `80 18`, sauf bien sûr là où septante et nonante sont l'usage.
- ce découpage par deux ou trois chiffres se retrouve dans la manière d'énoncer les numéros de téléphone en français.
- dans le dessin animé cité en commentaire, on entend une traduction peu idiomatique mais acceptable; les décimales y sont prononcées comme un nombre entier:

  `23,36664289109` -> **vingt-trois virgule trente-six milliards, six-cent-soixante-quatre millions, deux-cent-quatre-vingt-neuf mille cent-neuf**.

Comment: À l'oral on entend parfois (pour éviter un certains nombre d'erreurs possibles sur les très longues séquences décimales) : vingt-trois virgule, suivi de onze chiffres : deux, six, six, six

Comment: @jlliagre Attendez ... dans une émission que j'ai mentionné, pourquoi je l'entends différemment ? (Voici est un lien, à la marque 0:40 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mXT7c3lswiQ) J'ai entendu le mot « milliard » dans la chaîne de les décimales. J'ai ici démandé cette question car cette prononciation est très rapide.

Comment: C'est une traduction peu idiomatique: *vingt-trois virgule trente-six milliards, six-cent-soixante-quatre millions, deux-cent-quatre-vingt-neuf mille cent-neuf*.

Comment: Y aurait-il des références intéressantes à ce sujet?

Comment: Pardon, je voulais parler de la réponse de jlliagre.

Comment: Pour réentendre une version ralentie du même nombre que dans l'extrait youtube du commentaire de dragon, on peut aussi l'écouter avec Google Translate : ça donne [ça](http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=%2223,36664289109%22&tl=fr).

Comment: Le regroupement des chiffres 2 par 2 est courant pour les numéros de téléphone, ou pour les centimes parce qu'il n'y a que 2 chiffres, mais je n'ai pas l'impression qu'il soit universel pour des décimales quelconques. Pi est plus souvent regroupé 3,14 159 que 3,14 15 92. Pour la question de départ, lire chaque chiffre un par un me semble assez courant aussi.

Comment: @MarcGlisse J'ai bien indiqué que le regroupement par deux n'est pas respecté quand le nombre de chiffres est impair comme avec *3,14 159* qui est différent de *3,14 15 92*. D'autre part, il me semble que lire les chiffres un par un n'est pas idiomatique en français (de France au moins), sauf parfois quand il s'agit d'une suite illimitée du même chiffre comme *zéro virgule trois trois trois trois trois ...*

Comment: Pardon, j'aurais dû en mettre plus long pour pi, je voulais dire que même pour une personne récitant les 100 premières décimales de pi, je crois que le regroupement 159 est fréquent. Mais je peux me tromper, et prononcer de nombreuses décimales est assez rare pour que les usages puissent facilement varier. D'autre part, mon échantillon (très anglophile) peut être biaisé et me convaincre à tort que lire les chiffres un par un est aussi naturel que deux par deux.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Le regroupement par trois est en effet aussi possible et courant. C'est même la forme enseignée à l'école (en indiquant millième, millionième, etc..)  je viens de modifier ma réponse pour en tenir compte. En revanche, l'énoncé de chaque décimale me semble bien un anglicisme.